# How to identify which instance of identical objects is clicked

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to use Jquery to identify which instance of an object was clicked if there are many identical objects on the page

I am working on an application which has a lot of input boxes named the same and I need to be able to validate design[z] if the corresponding design[x] and design[y] are not empty

e.g

```
<div><input name="design[x][]" type="text"><input name="design[y][]" type="text"><input name="design[z][]" type="text"></div>
<div><input name="design[x][]" type="text"><input name="design[y][]" type="text"><input name="design[z][]" type="text"></div>
<div><input name="design[x][]" type="text"><input name="design[y][]" type="text"><input name="design[z][]" type="text"></div>
<div><input name="design[x][]" type="text"><input name="design[y][]" type="text"><input name="design[z][]" type="text"></div>
<div><input name="design[x][]" type="text"><input name="design[y][]" type="text"><input name="design[z][]" type="text"></div>
<div><input name="design[x][]" type="text"><input name="design[y][]" type="text"><input name="design[z][]" type="text"></div>
```

if x and y on line 3 are not empty validate z on line 3
if x and y on line 5 are not empty validate z on line 5
but do not validate lines 1 2 or 6

unfortunately I cannot change what is being rendered on the page so I cant add unique identifiers

Thanks

Comment: on click $(this) will give you what element was clicked.

Comment: I recommend to read about the basics of jQuery event handling: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am working on an application which has a lot of input boxes named the same and I need to be able to validate design[z] if the corresponding design[x] and design[y] are not empty

Within your `click` handler, `this` is the element that was clicked. Then you can use `$(this)` to wrap it in a jQuery object, and [`.closest('div')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the container div. From the container div, you can find the other inputs via [`.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) or [`.children`](http://api.jquery.com/children) (since in this case, they are direct children of the div).

For instance:

```
$('input[name="design[x][]"]').click(function() {
    // Get the design[x][] element that was clicked
    var $x = $(this);

    // Get its parent div
    var div = $x.closest('div');

    // Get the corresponding design[y][] and design[z][]
    var $y = div.find('input[name="design[y][]"]');
    var $z = div.find('input[name="design[z][]"]');

    // ...do your work...
});
```

The same works regardless of which `input` you're hooking `click` on, you just have to adjust how you find them.

If you're hooking `click` on the `div`, then:

```
$('selector for the div').click(function() {
    // The div
    var div = $(this);

    // Get the corresponding design[x][], design[y][], and design[z][]
    var $x = div.find('input[name="design[x][]"]');
    var $y = div.find('input[name="design[y][]"]');
    var $z = div.find('input[name="design[z][]"]');

    // ...do your work...
});
```

---

In the above, note that the value of the `name` attribute is in quotes *within* the selector string, e.g.:

```
// These delimit the string --+
//                            |
//                +-----------+-------------+
//                |                         |
//                v                         v
var $y = div.find('input[name="design[y][]"]');
//                            ^           ^
//                            |-----+-----|
//                                  |
// These delimit the attr value ----+
```

The actual selector we're passing the engine is:

```
input[name="design[y][]"]
```

This is important, because your `name` attributes have `[]` in them. By putting the entire value in quotes, we're using the [rules for strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings) and so we don't have to worry about the `[]`. If we didn't put quotes around it, we'd have to put a bunch of unreadable backslashes in there, because without quotes you have to follow the rules for [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), which are much more restrictive.

Comment: At first, i didn't saw OP was using click handler, so this is correct answer for sure.

Comment: @T.JCrowder Is there no need to escape the brackets in the selector?

Comment: @KevinBowersox: Nope, that's what the quotes are for. I just commented on that part of your answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Just check this out](http://jsfiddle.net/QTCzv/2/), (click an item and look in the console)

```
$(function(){
    $("div input[type='text']").on('click', function(e){
       var item = $(this).attr('name');
       var ind = $(this).closest('div').index();
       var col = item.substr('design['.length, 1);
       var txtInd = { x:1, y:2, z:3 };

       console.log('Line : ' + (ind+1)); // 1-6 (row)
       console.log('Textbox : ' + txtInd[col]); // 1-3 (column)
       // Now do your logic
    });
});
```

`$(this)` points to the clicked item as a `jQuery` object. In this case `click` handlers registered on `text boxes`, so `$(this)` will point clicked `text-box`.